# ¿Como ir sumando los valores contados por count mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

no me estoy dando cuenta como hacer una consulta y por eso vengo a preguntar. Yo tengo la tabla Usuarios en la cual tengo las siguientes columnas:

```
id, nombre, numero1, numero2, email
```

Y la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT nombre, count(nombre) FROM Usuarios GROUP BY nombre HAVING count(nombre)>2
```

Lo que necesito es que la consulta seleccione filas en las que el `nombre` se repita más de 2 veces y además ir sumando los valores de (`numero1 * numero2`) de cada fila, dando un resultado final para poder ordenar los usuarios con `nombre` repetido en orden descendente, ¿cómo podría hacer eso?¿es posible en una sola consulta? Espero haberme explicado bien.

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer la suma, solo necesitas hacer `SUM(numero1 * numero2)`, y luego puedes ordenar las filas por ese resultado:

```
select nombre,
       count(*) as cnt,
       sum(numero1 * numero2) as valor_total
  from Usuarios
 group by nombre
 having count(*) > 2
 order by valor_total desc
```

Comment: Ahh yo estaba intentando con SUM(numero1 * numero2) pero no lo usaba con count(*), supongo que eso agarra todas las filas. Muchas gracias! Funciona excelente ahora. Edit: te vote positivo pero como tengo menos de 15 puntos no aparece.

Comment: En este caso, el que uses `count(*)` o `count(nombre)` no cambia nada, a menos que `nombre` pueda tener valores a `null`. Yo prefiero usar `count(*)` porque me parece mas claro la intención, pero eso no haría que funcione mejor.